# How to pinpoint the typeerror in my sequelize library within the node_modules?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

I'm writing a blog style assignment for a bootcamp. Our assignment is specifically to get us used to the MVC system. We are using sequelize for the database and handlebars for the templating engine. When I try to start my server by running `node server.js` I'm getting a `Reading properties of undefined` error within my node_modules.

```
annabellefosburgh@Annabelles-MacBook-Air demonic-dogs % node server.js
/Users/annabellefosburgh/Desktop/github repos/demonic-dogs/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:666
    options = Utils.merge(_.cloneDeep(globalOptions.define), options);
                                                    ^


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'define')
    at User.init (/Users/annabellefosburgh/Desktop/github repos/demonic-dogs/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:666:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/annabellefosburgh/Desktop/github repos/demonic-dogs/models/user.js:13:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/annabellefosburgh/Desktop/github repos/demonic-dogs/models/index.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)

Node.js v20.2.0
```

I do not understand what I have written that could cause an error in the node_modules code that I did not write.

I tried reinstalling sequelize expecting my node_modules to update with some new information. I also realized in my models I did not import files I used as foreign keys and added those and try to run it again, too. Unfortunately I'm VERY new to tech and so my understanding is not crazy high.

Comment: Show the code (/Users/annabellefosburgh/Desktop/github repos/demonic-dogs/models/user.js, line 13) that calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

When running your server.js code, `User` model in the user.js file is giving undefined behavior. Specifically, the error was when the
`User.init` function was called within the model.js file of Sequelize. The error log suggests that the globalOptions.define object is undefined or missing a define property.

Unless you provide the user.js file and its init step, the error could be either Sequelize is an incompatible version with the version of Node you are using (20.2.0), or it could be a misconfiguration step when Sequelize initializes the `globalOptions` object (and expects to receive a `define` property but doesn't).

Some debugging steps:

1. Run `npm list sequelize` and confirm the versions
2. Make sure `globalOptions.define` object is properly defined with the necessary options passed to it
3. Confirm that your packages are not incompatible, sometimes new versions of Node will break old version of packages, vice-versa, or some other complicated dependency tree issue in node_modules such as circular dependencies
4. Debug through user.js as the original error occurred here